# Leaving __init__.py blank doesn't seem to work

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have a very simple file setup:

```
test.py
package/
    __init__.py
    file_1.py
```

With the contents of each file being:

```
# in test.py
import package

# in file_1.py
foo = 5
```

With the `__init__` file being blank. I've been told on multiple occasions that leaving the `__init__` file blank is perfectly fine. Then why then, in `test.py` can I not access `foo` by saying `package.foo`? This seems incredibly trivial to me, yet I cannot figure out why it's not working. If I put a print function in `file_.py` that doesn't seem to get activated either upon running `test.py`, so what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like this. You cannot access `package.foo` since there is no `foo` in `package.__init__`. Since code in `__init__` doesn't import `file_1` or `file_1.foo`.

You can do `import package.file_1` and then access `package.file_1.foo` or `from package.file_1 import foo` and then access `foo`.

Also there can be no `__init__.py` at all.